# Summary shown in R is short, many terms shown as "Other"

Tags: r, summary

How can I display the complete output summary, without classifying any values as "Other"?

```
summary(d)
     Date.of.Sale   City               Department      Product     
 1/18/2015 :  149   A:5290   Footwear Mens  : 538   13245  :  255  
 1/25/2015 :  149   B:2078   Home Furnishing:1937   15350  :  255  
 11/23/2014:  149   C:5088   Infant W-Wear  : 992   15352  :  255  
 11/30/2014:  149            Ladies Lower   :1735   15353  :  255  
 12/14/2014:  149            Ladies Upper   :1805   15355  :  255  
 12/21/2014:  149            Mens Lower     :2039   15356  :  255  
 (Other)   :11562            Mens Upper     :3410   (Other):10926  
            Sale      Predicted.Sale       Flag      
 0            :3963   0      :3279   Forecast: 1341  
 Not Available:1341   1      :1951   History :11115  
 1            :1145   2      : 946                   
 2            : 797   3      : 700                   
 3            : 557   4      : 572                   
 4            : 498   5      : 438                   
 (Other)      :4155   (Other):4570
```

Comment: you may be looking for the `table` function, e.g., `table(d$Date.of.Sale)`

Answer (score 4):

**Aside:** It looks like your data has factor columns where they should be numeric.  You may want to have a look at that as it may cause issues for you in later analysis.

---

As far as your call to `summary()` goes, you can adjust the `maxsum` argument.  We find in `help(summary)` that this can be used to change the amount of information shown in the summary

> **maxsum** - integer, indicating how many levels should be shown for factors.

So let's have a look at this at work with a two-column data frame example -

```
set.seed(12)
df <- data.frame(
    a = sample(letters[1:8], 1e3, TRUE), 
    b = sample(letters[1:10], 1e3, TRUE)
)
```

Calling `summary()` with no other arguments, we get "Other" listed at the bottom of each column summary.

```
summary(df)
#       a             b      
# d      :132   g      :118  
# c      :131   b      :108  
# f      :131   e      :106  
# a      :123   f      :104  
# g      :123   d      :103  
# e      :122   j      :103  
# (Other):238   (Other):358
```

Now if we adjust `maxsum` to the length of the maximum number of unique values of all columns, we get all the values listed.

```
summary(df, maxsum = max(lengths(lapply(df, unique))))
#  a       b      
#  a:123   a: 94  
#  b:120   b:108  
#  c:131   c: 99  
#  d:132   d:103  
#  e:122   e:106  
#  f:131   f:104  
#  g:123   g:118  
#  h:118   h: 92  
#          i: 73  
#          j:103
```

Note that `maxsum` could also be `maxsum = length(Reduce(union, df))`, and that this assumes that you are working with a data frame.